# Ubuntu, No wireless networks found after correctly installed madwifi

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04

I just installed madwifi on my MSI laptop with an Atheros AR5001 wifi card & Lucid.
As far as I can see and according to System -> Administration -> Hardware drivers the install was successful and the card + driver is up and running.

However, I don't see any wireless network (my windows PC can see about 5 wireless networks). I tried it with the network manager applet as well as with wicd. If I try to connect to "Hidden Wireless Network" via nm-applet, it will start to connect for a while but is unable too (although I supply it with the correct WEP settings & key)

So, I'm unable to use my wireless network. What am i doing wrong?

Some information about my system:
iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wifi0     no wireless extensions.

ath0      IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:""  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power:17 dBm   Sensitivity=1/1  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/70  Signal level=-96 dBm  Noise level=-96 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

pan0      no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```
ath0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:af:cf:e2:ca  
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:afff:fecf:e2ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:85:4d:82:78  
          inet addr:192.168.2.101  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:85ff:fe4d:8278/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3940261 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:525218 (525.2 KB)
          Interrupt:27 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

wifi0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-15-AF-CF-E2-CA-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:280 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:179947 (179.9 KB)
          Interrupt:16
```

lshw -C network

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wifi0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:cf:e2:ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list logical ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath_pci latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11g
       resources: irq:16 memory:fd7f0000-fd7fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, turned out to be the on/off switch of the wireless that had both a weird symbol that I didn't recognize and that had to be pushed twice to turn on....